# Python if statement about object in list returns True even if object not in list

Tags: python, list

(MY CODE)`

```
o = [1,1,1,2,3,4]

if 99 and 98 or 97 and 96 in o:
    print("j")

#(OUTPUT)
j
```

why is output j? none of 99, 98, 97 or 96 is in o.
even if i add parenthesis and "in o" after 99, 98 etc,

i still get same thing.
im using vscode if it makes any difference

Comment: That is not how you test multiple conditions

Comment: Thank you very much pranav Hosangadi, this solution worked very well with the and operator but when I try something like                                                                          
 o = [1,1,1,2,3,4]

if all(x in o for x in [99,98] or [1,4]) == True:
    print("j")                                                                                                                                                         the output is nothin, so not "j", which I would think it should since 1 and 4 is in o.

Answer (score -1):

condition1:99 and 98 = True

conditiuon2: condition1 or 97 = True

condition3:condition2 and 96 = True

conditon4:condition3 in 0 = True

if True: print("j")

Comment: Yes this solution is very good! I should be more specific with my question because I want all my conditions in one line if code if that is possible.